# Selenium webdriver throwing timeout exception

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, timeoutexception

I am new to `Selenium`.

My issue is that I'm trying to click an element but `Selenium` is throwing a `timeout exception`, even if I increase the timeout value.

Do I need to use `xpath` instead of `id`?

The HTML Code is:

[image]
My code looks like this

```
 void searchquotation() throws TimeoutException {
    try {
          WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 15);
          WebElement element = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.name("SearchButton")));
          element.click();
       }
    catch(TimeoutException e) {
         System.out.println("Timeout occured");
       }
```

Am I doing anything wrong?

Comment: Please ensure first at browser console using this javascript document.getElementsByName('SearchButton') you are getting this button or not?

Answer (score 0):

The input type here is submit (by looking at your HTML code) so I would strongly advise to try the submit() function of Selenium.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `By.name`, you should use `By.id` instead. Therefore, use either of these:

1. `By.Id("SearchButton")`
2. `By.CssSelector("input#SearchButton")`
3. `By.Xpath("//input[@id='SearchButton']")`

Note: syntax could be wrong, please adjust depending on your programming language

Answer (score -1):

```
    try below code, even timeout exception occurs, it will try 4 time to click on it. assuming locator is correct By.name("SearchButton")

    public void searchquotation()
    int count=0;
    while(count<4)
    {
     try { 
    WebElement x = driver.findElement(By.name("SearchButton")));
    WebDriverWait element=new WebDriverWait(driver,15);
    element.until (ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.name("SearchButton"))); 
    x.click(); 
count=count+4;
    } 
    catch(TimeoutException e) { 
    count=count+1;
    System.out.println("Timeout occured");
    continue;
    }
    }
```

Comment: got it. The element is enclosed in a table Is there any different way to access an element wrapped in td Below is the HTML code
http://i.stack.imgur.com/WxJYp.jpg

Comment: Any answers from experts